# Gradle, IntelliJ and ScalaTest plugin: suddenly broken

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, gradle, scalatest

This is very puzzling. I have a multi module polyglot JVM project built using Gradle. I have a few java modules and a couple scala modules. The scala module uses ScalaTest as the test framework. I set up the Gradle to use the [scalatest plugin](https://github.com/maiflai/gradle-scalatest) to run tests. I had the whole thing running like a charm in IntelliJ for about a month (using the Gradle idea plugin). Now all of a sudden the ScalaTest specs won't run from the IDE anymore with the following error:

```
Unable to load a Suite class. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: com.mypackage.MySpec
```

Does anybody know what's going on? I am not sure what has changed since the first time I set up my build file that might have messed this up. This is really frustrating. Ideas?

**EDIT**: Apparently my junit tests won't run either. Looks like the compiled classes aren't on the classpath used by Intellij. This is what I get if I try to run a JUnit test case:

```
Class not found: "com.mypackage.MyUnitTests"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was messing with my IntelliJ configuration files after [this blog post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hell-intellij-and-gradle) and I accidentally messed up my project output folder (in the `updateBuildOutputFolderForGradle` function) so that IntelliJ wasn't able to find the classes at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that since this is a multi-language project IntelliJ can't tell which are the source folders. Check under `Project Structure` > `Modules` (each of your module) and ensure `Sources` and `Tests` dirs are correctly marked.

Comment: The OP is using Gradle and so setting source and test directories should be done in `build.gradle`, not in IntelliJ's `Project Structure` screen, because as soon as you re-import your Gradle project, those settings will be overridden with whatever is in your `build.gradle`.